# Difference between types of private keys?

Tags: authentication, key

I've been doing some research on types of encryption keys/secrets and I have come across a slight hiccup in my understanding. I have been unable to tell the difference between the types of private keys available.

Such as the following:

- Private Signature Key
- Private Authentication Key
- Private Key Transport
- Private Static Key
- Private Authorization Key

On several sites, I have seen lists of these keys, but the description's all seem the same to me. If anyone has any available reading for me, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick set of descriptions, from the ever-useful [Cryptographic Key Types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_key_types) page on Wikipedia (*italics* are my simple explanation):

**Private signature keys** are the private keys of asymmetric (public) key pairs that are used by public key algorithms to generate digital signatures for long term use... can be used to provide authentication, integrity and non-repudiation.

*This could be your key, used for signing data you send, to prove it was you who sent it and that the data hasn't been tampered with.*

A **private authentication key** is the private key of an asymmetric (public) key pair that is used with a public key algorithm to provide assurance as to the integrity of information, and the identity of the originating entity or the source of messages, communication sessions, or stored data.

*This differs slightly from the first one in that there isn't an expectation of non-repudiation*

**Private key transport keys** are the private keys of asymmetric (public) key pairs that are used to decrypt keys that have been encrypted with the associated public key using a public key algorithm. Key transport keys are usually used to establish keys (e.g., key wrapping keys, data encryption keys or MAC keys) and, optionally, other keying material (e.g., initialization vectors).

*This type, and the following one, are used to establish and decrypt short term keys which will be used to encrypt data*

**Private static key agreement keys** are the private keys of asymmetric (public) key pairs that are used to establish keys (e.g., key wrapping keys, data encryption keys, or MAC keys) and, optionally, other keying material (e.g., Initialization Vectors).

*This type, and the previous one, are used to establish and decrypt short term keys which will be used to encrypt data*

**A private authorization key** is the private key of an asymmetric (public) key pair that is used to provide privileges to an entity.

*Used as a token - ie the person with this key is allowed access to these files/areas*

I hope that helps a bit.